# Writing Date time and name onto a File Using Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I wish to write name along with date and time onto a file for this i
 use an arraylist.But when i write it onto file..a single name along
 with date appears twice; It is related somewhere to my implying
 StandardOpenOption.Append because when I don't it prints date and values
 once but does overwrite my previous values.][1]

```
//created method to write date and name onto file

public void standardRoom() 
{
    try {
        Path p=Paths.get("test/standardRoom.text");

        if(Files.notExists(p))
        {
            Files.createFile(p);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter Name");
        String name=sc.next();

        List<String>stdrooms=new ArrayList<>();

        date = d.toString();

        stdrooms.add(date); 
        stdrooms.add(name);

        System.out.println("Standard Room booked");

        Iterator<String>bookings=stdrooms.iterator();
        while(bookings.hasNext())
        {              
            String s=bookings.next();
            //Files.write(p, stdrooms);
            Files.write(p, stdrooms,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }          


}
}
```

Comment: Please, correct and align all indentations. Thanks.

Comment: Oops ! My bad.corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `date` and `name` to the list, `stdrooms` contains two elements.

The iterator `bookings` now has the size of the list. Therefore `Files.write` is executed twice:

```
    Files.write(p, stdrooms,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

When printing `stdrooms` containing both `date` and `name`, the default `toString` implementation is used, which in turn prints the whole list.

One solution might be to use `s` for printing instead of `stdrooms`:

```
    Files.write(p, s.getBytes(),StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: It shows Error. Argument mismatch if I use "s" instead of stdrooms; String cannot be converted to byte[]

Comment: `s.getBytes()` will return a byte array. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Perfect ! The way I want it...that was some miniscule crap !

Comment: Thanx man finally the program looks tidy

Comment: Glad I could help. You can mark it as the accepted answer or upvote it if you'd like.